# DISTINCT mysql query within a foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, foreach, mysqli

I need to query a database and return distinct values for columns. The query is in a foreach loop and varies based on an array.

```
$get_all_col_names = $this->db->list_fields($table_by_product);
//This will return "X_SIZE", "X_PRINT", "X_QTY"
```

Now I have a foreach which needs to get the distinct values of "X_SIZE", "X_PRINT", and "X_QTY" respectively.

```
foreach ($X_types as $X) {
   $this->db->select($X);
   $this->db->distinct();
   $qX = $this->db->get($table_by_product);
   return $qX->result_object();
}
```

The problem with this current setup is that it is only returning DISTINCT values for X_QTY which is the LAST array in the list.

I need distinct values returned for ALL keys in the array. How can I make this work? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't know if i know what you want... but making a return in a foreach, will do that after the first loop its already returned. If you want all your results returned, you must make your return AFTER the foreach and add add the results to a temp array which you return then.

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do. I tried `$X_types[] = array();` before the the foreach and then after the loop What do I put? Can you please clarify and make that your answer. You are prob right about what i need to do. Thanks

Comment: $resultArray = array();
foreach ($X_types as $X) {
   $this->db->select($X);
   $this->db->distinct();
   $qX = $this->db->get($table_by_product);
$resultArray[] = $qX->result_object();
}
return $resultArray;

Comment: @tenhouse please post an official answer so that I can accept your response and give you proper credit. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your foreach will return after the first round in the loop, try the following:

```
$resultArray = array(); 
foreach ($X_types as $X) { 
    this->db->select($X)$this->db->distinct(); 
    $qX = $this->db->get($table_by_product); 
    resultArray[] = $qX->result_object(); 
} 
return $resultArray;
```